# SpringBoot + Spring Security OAuth2 2.0 Resource Server JWT at Startup Expectation is not calling Authorisation Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

**Summary :**

Testing out Spring Security OAuth2 Resource Server JWT with SpringBoot 2.7.7 which uses Spring Security 5.7.6 to query Authorisation Server at startup.

According to :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#_startup_expectations

> **Startup Expectations**
>
> When this property and these dependencies are used, Resource Server
> will automatically configure itself to validate JWT-encoded Bearer
> Tokens.
>
> It achieves this through a deterministic startup process:
>
> - Query the Provider Configuration or Authorization Server Metadata endpoint for the jwks_url property
> - Query the jwks_url endpoint for supported algorithms
> - Configure the validation strategy to query jwks_url for valid public keys of the algorithms found
> - Configure the validation strategy to validate each JWTs iss claim against idp.example.com.
>
> A consequence of this process is that the authorization server must be
> up and receiving requests in order for Resource Server to successfully
> start up.
>
> If the authorization server is down when Resource Server queries it
> (given appropriate timeouts), then startup will fail.

I have the property defined in `application.properties` AND the dependencies in `pom.xml` as above.

However, my very small example to try this out does not work ( e.g. The Resource Server does not appear to be querying the Authorisation Server at all at startup, and therefore the Resource Server starts-up successfully.

I was expecting my very small app to fail at startup as per documentation, but it did not ! Went as far as shutting down the Authorisation Server, and the SpringBoot Resources Server app still starts up.

Here's what I did :

**1) pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>oauth2-resource-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
        <bootstrap.version>5.2.3</bootstrap.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency-->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**2. application.properties**

```
server.port=8081
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://openam.localtest.me:8080/openam/oauth2/realms/subrealm/
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=http://openam.localtest.me:8080/openam/oauth2/realms/subrealm/connect/jwk_uri
```

**3. Configuration class:**

```java
package org.example.oauth2resourceserver;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
    String jwkSetUri;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_message:read")
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_message:write")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(this.jwkSetUri).build();
    }
}
```

**4. Controller**

```java
package org.example.oauth2resourceserver;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class ExampleMVCController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String main(Model model) {
        return "welcome";
    }

    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

**5. Application**

```java
package org.example.oauth2resourceserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Oauth2ResourceServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Oauth2ResourceServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

With the Authorisation Server down, output on the console when I run the Resource Server is:

```
2022-12-28 03:32:38.148  INFO 1377958 --- [           main] o.e.o.Oauth2ResourceServerApplication    : Starting Oauth2ResourceServerApplication using Java 11.0.15 on xxxxx-Inspiron-15-7510 with PID 1377958 (/home/xxxxx/projects/oauth2-resource-server/target/classes started by jsalvo in /home/xxxxx/projects/oauth2-resource-server)
2022-12-28 03:32:38.150  INFO 1377958 --- [           main] o.e.o.Oauth2ResourceServerApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-12-28 03:32:38.561  INFO 1377958 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=12f14043-de4d-3b01-a8aa-ef038a41274e
2022-12-28 03:32:38.733  INFO 1377958 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2022-12-28 03:32:38.739  INFO 1377958 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-28 03:32:38.739  INFO 1377958 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.70]
2022-12-28 03:32:38.819  INFO 1377958 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-28 03:32:38.820  INFO 1377958 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 634 ms
2022-12-28 03:32:38.931  INFO 1377958 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@748ac6f3, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@68f6e55d, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2bfaba70, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5584d9c6, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@3bf54172, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@58af5076, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@650c405c, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@9301672, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2577a95d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6fff46bf, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@17e9bc9e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4da39ca9, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@2954f6ab]
2022-12-28 03:32:39.140  INFO 1377958 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2022-12-28 03:32:39.152  INFO 1377958 --- [           main] o.e.o.Oauth2ResourceServerApplication    : Started Oauth2ResourceServerApplication in 1.27 seconds (JVM running for 1.512)
```

- What am I missing ?
- What code in Spring Security OAuth2 Resource Server does the call to the Authorisation Server at startup ?

---

**UPDATE 2022-12-28**

As suggested by the comments, I have completely removed my *OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration* above. Still no luck.

On looking at the source code for [*OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.JwtDecoderConfiguration*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/6e3a87d315ae92f630adc577a6678075f2f014a0/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/servlet/OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.java#L138) :

It appears that you must only specify one of the following properties, but not both:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri
```

The method at :

[JwtDecoderConfiguration.jwtDecoderByIssuerUri() method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/6e3a87d315ae92f630adc577a6678075f2f014a0/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/servlet/OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.java#L138) has an `@IssuerUriCondition` annotation that dictates a condition where you must only have the `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri` property defined.

So I commented out the other property ( commented out `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri` from `application.properties`), but when I debug into that method via IntelliJ, it steps at line 139 below but it does not step / stop at line 141 within the lambda, which is where the code that actually calls the authorisation server, even if I try to Step-In ( F7 ) from line 139:

[image]

In short, I am still at a loss. Anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: It should be triggered by `oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)`. Set a breakpoint or a log line to check that your SecurityFilterChain bean is loaded.

Comment: can you please remove `.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);` and try again. As pointed out here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-sansboot you have overridden the autoconfigure feature, by defining your own custom security. The part you are linking to refers to using auto configuration.

Comment: Hi @ch4mp  ... I have added an update to the question above so that 1) Removed my *OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration* class, and 2) Debugged through the code from springboot OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.

Comment: Hi @Toerktumlare ... I have added an update to the question above so that 1) Removed my *OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration* class, and 2) Debugged through the code from springboot OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.

Comment: @jmsjr did you get anywhere with this I seem to be having a similar issue?

Comment: Hi @Schokea .. no I did not have this resolved and I now do NOT rely on the feature "authorization server must be up and receiving requests in order for Resource Server to successfully start up." ... as that does not seem to work.